# Wix Custom condition for not Installed, Uninstall and upgrade

Tags: wix

I have a vbscript to run to create backup of the already installed application.
I  have added it in a custom action.

NOT Installed OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE

Problem is during upgrade custom action is running twice..so i will have one more backup folder of previously installed one.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: <Custom Action="BackupFiles" Before="InstallFiles" >NOT Installed OR (REMOVE~="ALL") OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>

Comment: i want all "not Installed, Uninstall and upgrade" condition to be true.

Answer (score 2):

UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE is not what you want to use. You should use NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE.

This property is set by the installer when it is running the currently installed version of the msi within the installing MSI's server context. This is what is run when you run "RemoveExistingProducts" during the upgrade. The problem you have now is that your install that you are installing has "NOT Installed" = true  and "UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE" = false. When the installer runs the previous install to remove it this install has "NOT Installed" = false but "UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE" = true so it will run the custom action.

What I would consider setting the condition to would be

```
WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE AND NOT REMOVE~="ALL"
```

[Here's](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) some info on the WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED property

So this condition will only run when the install detects a previous version and we are upgrading but will not run when we are just removing the old version and will not run when uninstalling. I would also schedule RemoveExistingProducts afterInstallInitialize so that your backup is created at the earliest point during the server context of the MSI installation before any files are removed or updated.

Comment: I also want wix custom action to start the IIS whn MSI fails or roll back at the end..<CustomAction Id="IISRESET_START" Directory="TARGETDIR" ExeCommand='"[WindowsFolder]system32\IISRESET.exe /start"' Execute="deferred" Return='ignore'/>

Comment: You'll just need to make the Execute="rollback" and schedule it at the right spot. If you have an action that stops IIS, you should shcedule this rollback action before the one that stops it.